# How to install the .ipa file generated build link through diawi.com. without adding udid for testing 100 users

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

How to install the .ipa file generated build link through diawi.com. without adding udid.
Please help me. It is installed only for  particular device which udid is added in provisioning profile.

How is it possible, Please give me suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using individual developer account? Enterprise developer account?

As per my understanding about apple distribution process, you must have Enterprise developer account to install the ipa file on any iOS device without adding UDID in the provisioning file.

Answer (score 0):

No , with diawi you won't be able to install the app without providing UDID.
But [TestFlight Beta Testing](https://subodhnpushpak.wordpress.com/2015/01/05/deploying-ios-apps-without-udid-to-beta-testers-using-testflight-beta-testing/) for iOS applications will help you to test app without being worried about UDID.